# Angular 12: ERROR Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a config file with a function as  property value:

```
const conf = {
   decoratorFunc: (val: string) => inject(MyCustomPipe).transform(v)
},
```

when I use this property in my COmponent as:

```
private someMethod(){
  conf.decoratorFunc('Test');
}
```

I get the error

```
> ERROR Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
>   at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:4768:15)
>   at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:4778:12)
```

I tried adding `"paths": { "@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ] }` but did not help. I am using Angular 12

Comment: you can't call `inject` during method execution, but you can call it inside of a component instantiation. If you describe what you are trying to do, SO community could help you to find better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Injector instead, try this:

```
const conf = {
  decoratorFunc: (val: string) =>
    Injector.create({
      providers: [{ provide: MyCustomPipe, useClass: MyCustomPipe }],
    })
      .get(MyCustomPipe)
      .transform(val),
};
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-a2bnym?file=src%2Fmain.ts